# Can Python export latitude/longitude from Satellite images?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, geolocation

I have a satellite image and it has latitude/longitude for each pixel.
Can I export the coordinate value of each pixel to .CSV file or .txt file by using Python?
If it can ,how to do that?

Comment: where is latitude and longitude stored

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: I doubt that the LL-data is stored explicitly for every pixel. Maybe you will find the coordinates of the four corners in the metadata. Then simply loop over the interpolated coordinates of the pixels to create the csv file. You did not mention whether the csv file should contain the brightness or color value of the pixel itself. Should it?

Comment: There is a variety of formats for satellite image data, some of which are well supported by Python products. Which format did you receive the image in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can export latitude/longitude from satellite images. For .tif images Below is the source code.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio as rio

tifImage = "imagename.tif"

def extractLatLon(imageName, NumOfBands):

```
with rio.open(imageName) as src:
    image = src.read(NumOfBands)
    height, width = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
    rows, cols = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))
    xs, ys = rio.transform.xy(src.transform, rows, cols)
    lat, lon = np.array(xs), np.array(ys) 
    return lat, lon
    # Flatten lat, lon if you want to [according to your needs]
```

def DataFrame(lat, lon):
return pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}).to_csv('File_name_to_be_saved.csv')

lat, lon = extractLatLon("ImageName.tif", NumOfBands=3)
DataFrame(lat, lon)